# enable only one checked box in ionic4 app

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to enable only one checkbox in a ionic 4 app, I have begin some code but now I am stuck, I think I have to use `ngModel`.. 
I'd like to changed `reponse.checked` to right when it's checked and then give false to all other checked of my array...

html

```
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-title>
      Question 1
    </ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle>
        Test
      </ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-list>
              <ion-item *ngFor='let rep of reponse'>
                <ion-label>{{rep.name}}</ion-label>
                  <ion-checkbox 
                  [(ngModel)]="isChecked"
                  color="primary" 
                  slot="start"></ion-checkbox>
              </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
  </ion-card>
```

.ts

```
export class SurveyPage implements OnInit {

reponse = [
  {
    name: 'test',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    checked: false
  },
];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

isChecked( {

});

}
```

Comment: it is the defaultbehavior of a radiobutton, why do you use a checkbox then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ngModelChange` to reset other selected item

```html
<ion-item *ngFor='let rep of reponse;let i = index'>
         <ion-label>{{rep.name}}</ion-label>
           <ion-checkbox 
                  [(ngModel)]="rep.checked"
                  color="primary" 
                  (ngModelChange)="updatedCheckList(i)"
                  slot="start">
           </ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

updatedCheckList methosd

```js
updatedCheckList(itemIndex:number) {
   this.reponse.forEach((rep,index) =>{
     if (itemIndex !== index) {
       rep.checked = false
     }
    })
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-7daf7w)

Comment: @Yann92 happy to help why you don't use radio instead of checkbox ?

Comment: I will, I did not know it exists. But good things, I have understood the use ngModelChange